# How to get a D365 List about ISV (localization/partner) packages installed?

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

I would like to get a D365 List about ISV (localization/partner) packages installed?

I can check in to "Help and support" > About

[image]

But is there any way in order to have a list?

**Update on 20 April 2022
I'm able to access to LCS and to Environment machine too.
I would like to extract the list like in AX2012 or other way (if It's possible) in order to manage in Excel/TXT. The Help > About list way is to hard to export in to Excel/TXT list.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to answer some questions: Do you only have access to the web ui and not e.g. LCS or the version control repository? And what is your requirement for a list that is not covered by the Help > About list?

Comment: Since this question does not seem to be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow, I will just give some remarks: "list like in AX2012" is probably refering to the "Models installed" form. I'm not aware that such a form exists in the D365FO web ui. The Help > About form allows to select and copy the list of installed packages. Non standard packages are listed with their layer. In LCS, you can download the deployable package and retrieve the list from there. On the environment machine, you can retrieve the list from the packages folder.